# A question about Lüroth's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Shafarevich says the following:

> Using Lüroth's theorem, we see that if $X$ is a rational curve, then $k(X)$ is isomorphic to the field of rational functions $k(t)$.

This is equivalent to saying that we can somehow prove that $t\in k(X)$. How is this true if the curve is $(t,t^2+1)$?

Comment: What Shafarevich is saying is that if $X$ is rational, then $k(X)$ is a simple transcendental extension of $k$. The symbol $t$ is arbitrary; it just denotes any generator of the extension. I don't understand what you mean when you say "we can somehow prove that $t \in k(X)$." What is your $t$?

Comment: On that curve isn't $t$ the function that maps a point to its first coordinate? Mapping a point to its second coordinate is in $k[t]$ as well, so no problem? But what Asal Beag Dubh says: Lüroth's theorem comes to play in a more general situation (when $t$ is not necessarily either one of the coordinate functions).

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh- $t$ is the variable with respect to which the rational curve is defined. For example, $(t,t^2+1)$ is a rational curve in $\Bbb{R^2}$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: ok, then Jykri's comment answers your question. On your curve, $t$ is a perfectly good rational function. Where is the problem?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: sorry my previous comment transposed the 'r' and the 'k' in your name.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- Mapping a point to its first coordinate; isn't that a many-one mapping?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh- You mean that the irreducible curve $X$ does not satisfy any non-trivial polynomial in $k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$? Why is this not true for a reducible curve?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: no, I did not mean that. All I meant is what I said: sending a point to its first coordinate is a rational function.

Comment: It's many-to-one in general but not in your example case. But as Asal Beag Dubh says it doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here presumably $X$ is a rational curve in some affine (or projective, makes no difference) curve, $X \subset \Bbb{A}^n$. So the points $P$ of $X$ are gotten from a recipe like
$P=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, where $x_i=g_i(t)$ for some rational functions $g_1(t),g_2(t),\ldots,g_n(t)\in k(t)$. The function field of $X$ is thus
$$
k(X)=k(g_1(t),g_2(t),g_3(t),\ldots,g_n(t)).
$$
Because the functions $g_i(t)\in k(t)$, it follows that $k(X)\subseteq k(t)$. Because $X$ is a curve, the field $k(X)$ contains elements that are $\notin k$. Therefore Lüroth's theorem kicks in, and we can conclude that $k(X)=k(u)$ for some element $u\in k(t)$. For all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ we have $g_i(t)\in k(X)$, so this means that $g_i(t)=h_i(u)$ for some rational function $h_i$.

In the example case
$$
X=\{(t,t^2+1)\in\Bbb{A}^2\mid t\in k\}
$$
there is no problem, as 
$$
k(X)=k(t,t^2+1)=k(t).
$$
Lüroth's theorem comes to the fore, when we use more complicated parametrizations. For example, it is not immediately clear what is the natural parameter $u$ for a curve like
$$
X=\{(\frac{t+t^2}{1+t^5+t^6+t^9+t^{10}},\frac{1+t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6}{t+t^8})\mid t\in k\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying some points! But the book says Luroth's theorem implies that for a rational curve $X$, $k(X)$ is isomorphic to $k(t)$, and not $k(u)$, where $u$ is some rational function of $t$. I don't understand how this is.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: The fields $k(t)$ and $k(u)$ are isomorphic because both $t$ and $u$ are transcendental over $k$.

Comment: And this should work even if $u$ is reducible?

Comment: That only amounts to a change of parametrization. In my answer we get the same curve from the parametrization 
$$X=\{(h_1(u),h_2(u),\ldots,h_n(u))\mid u\in k\}.$$

Comment: Here $u$ is just some element of $k(t)$. That is, a fraction with both numerator and denominator polynomials in $t$. I don't see when you would call such an object *reducible*?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: Basically what goes on is that the original parameter $t$ may have been a bad choice, and some other parameter works "better" (for a suitable definition of better). For example, your parabola could also be parametrized as $(t^{17},t^{34}+1)$. After the Lüroth magic we might realize that $u=t^{17}$ is a better choice. The curve and its function field are both immune to change $u\leftrightarrow t$.